# AWS のセキュリティグループ設定で、プロトコルの見方が分からない

Tags: aws

AWSのセキュリティグループ設定画面ですが、TypeとProtocolが自分の中でごちゃごちゃになっています。
HTTPがアプリケーション層、TCPがトランスポート層のプロトコルかと思いますが、以下の画像の設定だとHTTPがプロトコルではなくタイプとして指定されていて、TCPをプロトコルとして指定されています。

この画像はどのように読み解くのが正解なのでしょうか？

どなたかご存知の方、またそもそもの自分の認識が間違っていたら教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

それぞれ次のような関係です。

- **Type**
  わかりやすくするためだけの表示情報です。混乱するのであれば無視して構いません。実際この値は使われていません。
- **Protocol**
  [IPv4およびIPv6でのプロトコル番号](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%88%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AB%E7%95%AA%E5%8F%B7%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7)を指定します。TCPであれば`6`となります。
- **Port Range**
  ProtocolでTCPやUDPを指定した際、[ポート番号](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP%E3%82%84UDP%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E7%95%AA%E5%8F%B7%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7)を指定します。そのほかに[ICMPのType](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#%E9%80%9A%E7%9F%A5%E3%81%AE%E7%A8%AE%E9%A1%9E)も指定できるようです。HTTPであれば`80`となります。

セキュリティグループを操作するAPIは[`AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress.html)などになり、引数としては`IpProtocol`、`FromPort`、`ToPort`が該当しますが、Typeに相当する引数は存在しないことが確認できます。

Comment: わかりやすいご説明ありがとうございました！